# Custom CSS for Jupyter in Python Extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I would like to add custom icons to Jupyter by modifying the CSS within the Python extension.

I know where the CSS files are.  However, when I modify them directly, my modifications are completely ignored.

For example, if I modify the below file's contents:

```
../out/datascience-ui/history-react/menuBar.css
```

**From:**

```
.menuBar {
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: right;
 }
```

**To:**

```
.menuBar {
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: right;
    background-color: #b9b8b8;
 }
```

The line I added get completely ignored.  I'd like to know the easiest way to effectively make this change.  Ideally, I'd like to ask the developers of this extension on Github which they definitely know the answer.  However, Github isn't set up for getting this kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers on this extension. I answered on github, but I'd like to put the answer here as well in case anyone is looking here.

I don't think that going down the path of tweaking the .css file individually is going to give you the best results here. If you want to take a look at how the theming for the webview works I recommend starting with this file here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/src/client/datascience/codeCssGenerator.ts

It contains two things of interest, first off you can see how we scan the vs theme files to try to pull the correct files and surface them to our webview. And second, you can see the DefaultCssVars which is what we use for that "ignore theme" setting.

Comment: Thanks so much, Ian! I would be incredibly grateful if you could please tell me where in the CSSGenerator code I should modify in order for it to "think" my custom theme is a "vs" uiTheme instead of "vs-dark"? This would fool Jupyter into using light compatible svg images instead of dark ....which would resolve this issue completely. I'm guessing it may have something to do with the following line in "extension.js" from the Python extension:  r.hasOwnProperty("uiTheme") && "vs-dark" === r.uiTheme,

Comment: If not, could you please tell me what is the smallest change I can make in in the Python extension in order for Jupyter to use menubar icons (and other SVG images) meant for the light uiTheme **no matter what** (even if my custom theme specifies a "vs-dark" uiTheme)?  Eventually, I would like to do this programmatically in my custom theme.